# OpenEBS Jiva volume went to Read Only due to Controller Pod got evicted

Tags: openebs

I am using OpenEBS 0.6.0 on k8s 1.12.0. Jiva volume went to read only due to controller pod got evicted. This happens when node was on low resource and Jiva controller is not doing any ephemeral storage requests but it just output a log file. With modern kube, if a pod writes a single file it is considered to be using `ephemeralStorage` and if it has no request for `ephemeralStorage`, it is a candidate for eviction. because the disk has 250G, 15% of that is 35G and it will evict crtl pod.

```
Status:             Failed
Reason:             Evicted
Message:            The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container maya-volume-exporter was using 52Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container pvc-12bf95df-e8b6-11e8-b3bb-0050569f015b-ctrl-con was using 520Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
```

how can I give OpenEBS a request for ephemeralstorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller pod consumes ephemeral storage only for logs..
You can patch the controller deployment with requests setting a minimum of 1G and a maximum of 2G. This issue would be fixed in OpenEBS release 0.8.1, github /openebs/openebs/issue 2294